# What is the correct way to handle transferring calls under TaskRouter?

Tags: twilio

I intend to use Twilio's TaskRouter to handle incoming calls and assign them to workers in my system. The question I have is, if a worker is handling a call and they need to transfer it to another worker, what is the correct way to go about this? I assume that I need to ensure that the target worker becomes unavailable for task assignment, and the current worker becomes available at the very least. Do I create a task and somehow assign it to a specific worker? I couldn't find anything in the docs about assigning a task to a specific worker, or updating a worker's status, but I very well may have overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to have a closer look at these two entities in the REST API.

Workers: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workers#resource-properties

Tasks: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/tasks#task-attributes

Specifically, updating the workers `Available` attribute to 'true' or 'false' depending on the workers assignment.

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioTaskRouterClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
workspace_sid = "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
worker_sid = "WKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

client = TwilioTaskRouterClient(account_sid, auth_token)

activity = client.workers(workspace_sid).update(worker_sid, available="false")
print(activity.friendly_name)
```

I'd also suggest taking a look at this [TaskRouter tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/dynamic-call-center/csharp/mvc#1) to see an end-to-end example.

Please let me know if I can expand upon this at all to help further.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is tranferring the call via twiml and manually updating the status the preferred way to do this? What if the target worker is busy? Is there a way to create a task that targets a specific worker so that it can be queued? I read about TaskQueues, but I'm not sure if creating a TaskQueuenthat targets one specific worker is the way to go.